# Tensor product of fields from Romyar Sharifi's lecture notes. $K[X]/(f) \otimes_K M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I'm going through [Romyar Sharifi's lecture notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/algnum.pdf) on ANT.  In the first section, titled "Tensor product of fields", there's the isomorphism:

$$
f: K[X]/(f) \otimes_K M \simeq M[x]/(f)
$$

an isomorphism of $M$-algebras, where $f \in K[X]$ is monic and irreducible, and $M \supset K$ is an extension of fields.

$K[X]/(f) \otimes_K M$ is generated by elements of the form $\bar{g} \otimes m = (g + (f))\otimes m$ where $g \in K[X]$ and $m \in M$.  Was wondering how to interpret $\overline{g} \otimes m$?  Is it defined to be something?

Comment: If it's $g \otimes m + (f)$, then again, how do we interpret $g \otimes m$ for $g$ a polynomial?  Is it defined to be acting on the coefficients, or does it just equal that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking what the symbol $a \otimes b$ means in $A\otimes B$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$?

Comment: @Callus-ReinstateMonica I know what it means in the case of $K \otimes_K M$, but not sure in the case of the polynomial ring in place of $K$.  Remember, I have to somehow get to $M[x]/(f)$.

Comment: Depending on what you know for $K \otimes M$, the answer is "it means the same thing".  I'll try to write up an answer below, but do me one more solid and post here what it means to you in the case you understand.

Comment: @Callus-ReinstateMonica  $K \otimes_K M$ is the free module on $K \times M$ quotiented by 3 relations (giving it a module structure) and then a multiplication $(a\otimes b)(c\otimes d) := ac \otimes bd$ is defined giving the tensor product of $K$-modules a ring structure turning it into a $K$-algebra.   So that $a \otimes b$ is really $(a,b) + M$ where $M$ is the submodule of relations quotiented by.  In your answer, please say how $\overline{g} \otimes m$ should map into $M[X]/(f)$.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is fairly easy to define:  map the element $\bar{g}\otimes m$ to $m\cdot \bar{g}$, where that second product is just scalar multiplication ( i.e. multiply all the coefficients by $m$ ).

There are several abuses of notation in there, and a big caveat that we have to check the map is well-defined, so let me be more verbose.

$\bar{g}\in K[X]/(f)$ is represented by $g\in K[X]$.  $K$ is a subfield of $M$, given by an inclusion map $i:K\to M$.  We can use $i$ to define a map from $K[X]$ to $M[x]$ by mapping all the coefficients using $i$ and mapping $X$ to $x$.  Call this map $\phi: K[X]\to M[x]$.  This map is injective.  When we write $M[x]/(f)$, that's an abuse of notation that means $M[x]/(\phi(f))$.  And when I wrote "$\bar{g}$" in the expression $m\cdot \bar{g}$ I was using $\bar{g}$ to reference an element of $M[X]/(\phi(f))$.  That is another abuse of notation.  It should be $\bar{\phi(g)}$, where the bar over the top in this case means the coset $(\phi(g)+(\phi(f))$.  I'm pretty sure that's all the abuses of notation. The abuses of notation here are really not that bad; we're just taking the "same" polynomials and thinking of the coefficients as belonging to a larger field.

So now there's a couple of things left to show.  The biggest is probably that this map is well-defined; I defined it by referencing a representative of the coset $\bar{g}$, so you have to check that the image does not depend on the choice of representative.  You also have to check that the map is a ring-homomorphism and $M$-linear.

Finally, you have to check that it's bijective.  I believe that is again straightforward.

I spent most of the time above explaining the abuses of notation, because I believe that's what's tripping you up, but let me know if you're still confused ( or more confused).